# Application not running, if I load .tar and run image in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-image

I'm loading tar file using:

```
$docker load -i C:/temp/new/testing.tar
```

Now I did:

```
$docker images
```

New image, "testingready", can be seen.

now I'm running this image:

```
$docker run testingready
```

> - Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
> - Restarting with stat
> - Debugger is active
> - Debugger PIN: 201-301-249

And my docker-machine ip is some `xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa`

Now I'm trying to run my application on `xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa:5000` its not running,

As in parent system(where i created image) it running. I'm not getting where is the problem.

Comment: what does it say if your the command - 1. `docker ps -a`, 2. `docker logs <container id>`. Please update the questions with these requested info.

Comment: Do you use docker for Windows?

Comment: did you EXPOSE your ports?

Comment: @Mat, `EXPOSE` on `Dockerfile` is not necessary to publish a port. It is just for a type of documentation. refer this [description](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)

Comment: docker ps -a gives me list of contaigeners what i have, so I'm able to get all containers and images.

Comment: Same issue with me. can any one help on above question.